# Saber cuando una subview se va a remover de un uiviewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

Tengo una vista de olvidar contraseña, al hacer click en restablecer contraseña se abre un modal indicando que abras tu correo para continuar.Al hacer click deberia de mostrar la view de Login. Lo que sucede es que cuando haces click en el modal, éste ejecuta el método

```
self.removeFromSuperview()
```

El modal es de tipo UIView, los UIView tienen el método para saber cuando se va a remover de la vista padre.

```
    override func willRemoveSubview(_ subview: UIView) {
    print("esta por removerse")
}
```

En ese método pienso que es donde iría el código para redirigir al Login.
Mi problema es que al no ser controlador, no tiene un método como el que usas para cambiar de vistas, con el navigation controller, como este:

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

o este

```
self.present()
```

Entonces lo que ocupo es que al removerse el modal, me muestre la view de login. No se si se pueda realizar desde el view que invoca al modal, como con un listener o algo. O desde el mismo modal reedirigir al Login

Answer (score 0):

El modal se muestra encima de la vista que lo manda llamar, al tratarse de un restablecer contraseña, en teoría debería de mostrarse desde el login, entonces es suficiente con hacerle dismiss a tu modal y quedaría en la pantalla de login

Answer (score 0):

Espero esto te ayude.

Puedes implementar un patrón de delegado (Muy común en IOS), delegando algunas funcionalidades de tu UIView. te dejo un fragmento:

```
protocol  MyModalViewDelegate: class{
    func dissmissModal(_ view:MyModalView)
}

class MyModalView: UIView{

     weak var delegate: MyModalViewDelegate?

     override func willRemoveSubview(_ subview: UIView) {
        self.delegate?.dissmissModal(self)
     }
 }
```

y en el controlador al momento de crear tu ventana modal:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController,MyModalViewDelegate{

    func openModal(){

       let modal = MyModalView()
       modal.delegate = self
       self.view.addSubview(modal)
    }

  func dissmissModal(_ view: MyModalView) {
    print("aca se ejecuta cuando el modal va a desaparecer")
  }
}
```

PD: Considero que hay mejores formas de crear un modal custom, pero esta definitivamente debería ayudar en tu escenario.

Saludos.